# C - expanding the contents of a string

Tags: c, string

I am writing a function which expands the string, str1 and stores it as str2. By expansion, I mean if str1 has "a-d", it should be stored in str2 as "abcd". I have written the following code. I get a debug error that stack around the variable str1 is corrupted. 
Can someone please point out what's going wrong? 
Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void expand(char s1[], char s2[]);

int main() {

    char s1[] = "Talha-z";
    char s2[] = "";

    expand(s1, s2);
    printf(s2);

}

void expand(char s1[], char s2[]) {
    int i = 0;
    int j= 0;
    int k, c_next;

    while ( s1[i] != '\0') {
        switch (s1[i]) { 
        case ('-') :  
            c_next = s1[i+1]; 
            for ( k = 1; k < c_next; k++) {
                s2[j] = s1[i] + k;
                j++;
            }
            break;
        }

        i++;
        j++;
    }
    s2[j] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: by "expanding", you're writing beyond the end of the original string. You have to use dynamic memory allocation and realloc() for this.

Comment: It might be worth explaining any other requirements. What should "Yalha-z" produce? What should happen when str1 doers not contain a '-'? What should  happen if it starts or ends with '-'?

Answer (score 3):

You are not allocating sufficient memory for your target string (`s2`).  But you are attempting to write to it, which means you will be writing into memory that you don't own, causing the corruption.

You will need to use dynamic allocation for `s2` (i.e. by using `malloc`), but you will first need to calculate how much memory you need.

Comment: thanks, i have fixed that. I don't get the result as expected though. wonder if i am doing the case in switch right?

Comment: @yukon: You should debug your program, either by running it through the debugger, or by adding lots of print statements to observe intermediate values of variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
char s2[] = "";
```

This is equivalent to writing

```
char s2[1] = { '\0' };
```

It cannot hold more than a single character (or none at all, if the NUL terminator is required).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you initialize s2, you give it enough room for 1 character (i.e. the null terminating '\0'). Thus when you write into s2:

```
s2[j] = ...
```

there are no guarantees about what memory you're writing into.

To allocate memory for s2 dynamically, you need to use [malloc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation). In other words, you need to figure out how much memory is required (i.e. by finding the length of the expanded string) and then give s2 that much memory, and finally fill it in via the procedure you have written.

Answer (score 0):

The string s2 at present is on the stack for local variables for main() and is allocated only one byte for one character. When you call the function, it gets passed stack addresses for s1 and s2. The code is over-writing whatever is next to s2 on the stack of function main(). Hence, the error. Please use dynamic memory allocation as already suggested by Mr. Oli above.

Hope my explanation helps you.